# Overlay Polygons in ggplot2 and make the overlay transparent

Tags: r, ggplot2, layer

I'd like to make an overlay of several polygons with ggplot. The overlay's fill should be transparent but their borders should be red. I want to see only the fill of the first polygon so I thought to make the overlays transparent...but I can't get them fully transparent. Somehow I would be easier to just define the fill color as no-fill...but I don't know how to do it. Any ideas?

Here is some code to reproduce an example:

```
    ids <- factor(c("1.1", "2.1", "1.2", "2.2", "1.3", "2.3"))

    values <- data.frame(
      id = ids,
      value = c(3, 3.1, 3.1, 3.2, 3.15, 3.5)
    )

    positions <- data.frame(
      id = rep(ids, each = 4),
      x = c(2, 1, 1.1, 2.2, 1, 0, 0.3, 1.1, 2.2, 1.1, 1.2, 2.5, 1.1, 0.3,
            0.5, 1.2, 2.5, 1.2, 1.3, 2.7, 1.2, 0.5, 0.6, 1.3),
      y = c(-0.5, 0, 1, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1.5, 1, 0.5, 1, 2.1, 1.7, 1, 1.5,
            2.2, 2.1, 1.7, 2.1, 3.2, 2.8, 2.1, 2.2, 3.3, 3.2)
    )

    datapoly <- merge(values, positions, by=c("id"))

    p <- ggplot(datapoly, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_polygon(aes(fill=value, group=id))
    # overlay the same plot with red borders and transparent fill
    p <- p + geom_polygon(aes(group=id, alpha=1),colour="red",size=1.1)
    p
```

[image: without overlay]
[image: with overlay]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the second set of `geom_polygon` to not be filled in, just set the `fill` to `NA`.

```
ggplot(datapoly, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=value, group=id)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(group=id), alpha=1,colour="red", fill=NA, size=1.1)
```

[image]

In this case, you don't need two `geom_polygon` calls, though

```
ggplot(datapoly, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=value, group=id), colour="red", size=1.1)
```

Comment: Thank you. that's what I was searching for. and yes you're right, in this example there is no need for two polygons. I just used this code because it is easy to reproduce.